# Why is Mesa so slow?

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl

I was working on Windows with LWJGL and I got around 3000 FPS with a blank window. Now when doing the same thing on Linux, I get only 60. I suppose this is to do with Mesa/Open Source Graphics Drivers, but why are they so slow compared to Windows?

Comment: Make sure you are using a hardware accelerated OpenGL driver. Make sure you have vertical sync disabled.

Answer (score 3):

You can't benchmark absolutely anything with a blank window. And also 60 fps may be caused by VSync.

Comment: VSync is disabled, and I know that calculating FPS of a blank window isn't the best way of benchmarking but a drop from 3000 to 60? That's got to mean something

Comment: @MertcanEkiz: 60FPS is the update frequency of most displays. This reeks of V-Sync. How did you make sure you're not limited by that?

Comment: Like I said, I tried the same code in Windows and I got around 3000 FPS, and V-Sync is disabled in my program, so that should not be the thing that's limiting my FPS I think